# Change react-beautiful-dnd draggable click area

Tags: reactjs, draggable, react-beautiful-dnd

I am using react-beautiful-dnd

Cant find any solution for change Draggable click area.
I need drag items when I click in custom area (not at whole Draggable element).

For example, Draggable element has Icon and text. Default behavior let me drag item when I click any place of that element.

I need click only on icon for drag element.
**How can I specify click area for drag element?**

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Solution:
Just move `{...provided.dragHandleProps}` from Draggable div to child, what you want use as a drag area.
Example:

```
<Draggable draggableId="draggable-1" index={0}>
    {(provided) => (
        <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps}>
            <div {...provided.dragHandleProps}>DRAG AREA HERE</div>
            <li>item</li>
        </div>
    )}
</Draggable>
```

Comment: Beware: I changed this, but my nextjs autoreloader had some odd behavior resulting in a  `dragHandle not found` error. Killing the dev server and restarting it fixed it, and haven't had an issue with a compiled build. Likely a `react-beautiful-dnd` bug.